# Jquery is not triggering?

Tags: jquery

I am making a Question and Answer page. I have the output and I know Jquery is loaded bc I can't see it with Google Chrome inspector but I can't get a click to work...

```
<div class="faq-question">
                        <?php
                        // display a sub field value
                            echo '<p>Question: </p>';
                            the_sub_field('faq_question');
                        ?>
                        <a href="#" class="";></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="faq-answer"">
                        <?php
                        // display a sub field value
                            echo '<p>Answer: </p>';
                            echo '<div class="faq-answer-answer">';
                                the_sub_field('faq_answer');
                            echo '</div>';
                        ?>
                        <a href="#" class="";></a>
                    </div>

    <script>
$( ".faq-answer").hide();
$( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: wrap jquery code inside `document.ready()` block..your jquery code will be like $(document).ready(function(){$( ".faq-answer").hide();
$( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    alert("hello");
});});

Comment: *"I know Jquery is loaded bc I can't see it with Google Chrome inspector"* -what??

Comment: Where is the `</script>` tag? Other than that, Seems to be [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/r7bdyLzq/) voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

add few characters between anchor tag like `<a href="#">text</a>` and

where is `$(document).ready();`

It should be similar to this (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".faq-answer").hide();
  $( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: For jQuery script to work you have to use $(document).ready();

Comment: No. it's just a good practice, which doesn't have any impact in this particular scenario.